# window.open doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, pdf

Following works perfectly in Firefox:

I have following in javascript:

```
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10');
}
```

And 2 anchor links on my webpage:

```
    <a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://blablabla/ReferenceManua.pdf#page=31');
        Reference Manual 31</a>
    <br />
    <a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://blablablaReferenceManua.pdf#page=61');">
        Reference Manual 61</a>
```

When clicking on the 1st link, a new window opens, the pdf file is loaded, the url indicates it has to jump to page 31 and so it jumps to page 31       --> OK

When then clicking on the 2nd link, the same window is used, the url indicates it has to jump to page 61 and so it jumps to page 61         --> OK

In chrome however...
When clicking on the 1st link, a new window opens, pdf file is loaded, the url indicates it has to jump to page 31 and so it jumps to page 31       --> OK

but when clicking on the 2nd link, the same window is used, the url indicates it has to jump to page 61 but it stays on page 31     --> ??

In IE even worse:
A new window is created everytime i click on either link. Jumping to the requested page doesn't happen

How to solve this?

thank you

Comment: Is the missing `/` in the 2nd link intentional? Why do you want this in a popup? I hate links that I can't ctrl-click, middle mouse click or right-click>Open in a new window, because someone thought it would be cool to make JavaScript-only links. It drastically impairs usability.

Comment: You're also missing closing " in the first anchor

Answer (score 1):

I believe forcing window to close (if it is open) should solve the issue. Change your JS code to:

```
var popupWindow;

function newPopup(url) {
    if (popupWindow) popupWindow.close();

    popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the **same window name** thats why it opens in same window
If you want a separate one then you can try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DX86L/1/)

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 
window.open('yoururl',"_blank",'PopUp'+randomnumber+',scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');
```